# Memory visibility semantics of two related volatile variables

Tags: java, memory, volatile, jls, java-memory-model

Consider the following program from the [JLS section on volatile fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)

```
class Test {
    static volatile int i = 0, j = 0;
    static void one() { i++; j++; }
    static void two() {
        System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);
    }
}
```

Consider two thread are concurrently executing method `one()` and `two()`.

JLS states the following:

> This allows method one and method two to be executed concurrently, but
>   guarantees that accesses to the shared values for i and j occur
>   exactly as many times, and in exactly the same order, as they appear
>   to occur during execution of the program text by each thread.
>   Therefore, the shared value for j is never greater than that for i,
>   because each update to i must be reflected in the shared value for i
>   before the update to j occurs. It is possible, however, that any given
>   invocation of method two might observe a value for j that is much
>   greater than the value observed for i, because method one might be
>   executed many times between the moment when method two fetches the
>   value of i and the moment when method two fetches the value of j.

I am really confused by the above citation because it says two contradictory statements:

1. The shared value for `j` is **never** greater than that for `i`.
   (emphasis mine).
2. Value for `j` that is much greater than the value observed for `i`.

The first statement makes sense to me because if we combine the program order rule(`i++` happening before `j++`) and the memory visibility guarantee of volatile (happens-before) I can sort of see why the value of `j` can't exceed `i`. But I an unable to see how the value of `j` can can far exceed `i`.

Can you please help me understand this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual value of `j` can never be greater than the actual value of `i` at any given moment. But when the statement

```
System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);
```

is executed, `i` and `j` are not evaluated at the same moment. `j` is evaluated after `i` is. When `i` is evaluated, `j` is smaller or equal to `i`. But by the time `j` is evaluated, the other thread might have called the method `one()` many times, and both `i` and `j` might thus have been incremented many times. So `j` is still `<= i`, but what is printed could be

```
i=4 j=257
```

because it is in fact

```
at time t0, i=4
at time t1, j=257
```